# Reactive Spring Boot API wrapping Elasticsearch's async bulk indexing

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am developing prototype for a new project. The idea is to provide a Reactive Spring Boot microservice to bulk index documents in Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch provides a High Level Rest Client which provides an Async method to bulk process indexing requests. Async delivers callbacks using listeners are mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.8/java-rest-high-document-bulk.html). The callbacks receive index responses (per requests) in batches. I am trying to send this response back to the client as Flux. I have come up with something based on [this blog post](https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2018/01/spring-boot-2-fluxes-from-elasticsearch.html).

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class AppController {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test3", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Flux<String> index3() {
        ElasticAdapter es = new ElasticAdapter();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("TestDoc", "Stack123");
        Flux<String>  fluxResponse = es.bulkIndex(json);
        return fluxResponse;
    }
```

**ElasticAdapter**

```
@Component
class ElasticAdapter {
String indexName = "test2"; 
    private final RestHighLevelClient client;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;
    private int processed = 1;

    Flux<String> bulkIndex(JSONObject doc) {
        return bulkIndexDoc(doc)
                .doOnError(e -> System.out.print("Unable to index {}" + doc+ e));
    }

    private Flux<String> bulkIndexDoc(JSONObject doc) {
        return Flux.create(sink -> {
            try {
                doBulkIndex(doc, bulkListenerToSink(sink));
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                sink.error(e);
            }
        });
    }


    private void doBulkIndex(JSONObject doc, BulkProcessor.Listener listener) throws JsonProcessingException {

        System.out.println("Going to submit index request");
        BiConsumer<BulkRequest, ActionListener<BulkResponse>> bulkConsumer =
                (request, bulkListener) ->
                    client.bulkAsync(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT, bulkListener);
                    BulkProcessor.Builder builder =
                            BulkProcessor.builder(bulkConsumer, listener);
        builder.setBulkActions(10); 
        BulkProcessor bulkProcessor = builder.build();
        // Submitting 5,000 index requests ( repeating same JSON)
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexName, "person", i+1+"");
             String json = doc.toJSONString();
            indexRequest.source(json, XContentType.JSON);
            bulkProcessor.add(indexRequest);
        }
        System.out.println("Submitted all docs
    }


    private BulkProcessor.Listener bulkListenerToSink(FluxSink<String> sink) {
        return new BulkProcessor.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void beforeBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request) {
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void afterBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request, BulkResponse response) {

                for (BulkItemResponse bulkItemResponse : response) {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                    json.put("id", bulkItemResponse.getResponse().getId());
                    json.put("status", bulkItemResponse.getResponse().getResult

                    sink.next(json.toJSONString()); 
                    processed++;
                }
                if(processed >= 5000) {
                    sink.complete();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request, Throwable failure) {
                failure.printStackTrace();
                sink.error(failure);
            }
        };
    }


    public ElasticAdapter() {
    // Logic to initialize  Elasticsearch Rest Client 
    }
}
```

I used FluxSink to create the Flux of Responses to send back to the Client. At this point, I have no idea whether this correct or not.

My expectation is that the calling client should receive the responses in batches of 10 ( because bulk processor processess it in batches of 10 - `builder.setBulkActions(10);`  ). I tried to consume the endpoint using Spring Webflix Client. But unable to work it out. This is what I tried

**WebClient**

```
public class FluxClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");
        Flux<String> responseFlux = client.get()
                  .uri("/test3")
                  .retrieve()
                  .bodyToFlux(String.class);
        responseFlux.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Nothing is printing on console as I expected. I tried to use `System.out.println(responseFlux.blockFirst());`. It prints all the responses as a single batch at the end and not in batches at .

If my approach is correct, what is the correct way to consume it? For the solution in my mind, this client will reside is another Webapp.

Notes: My understanding of Reactor API is limited. The version of elasticsearch used is 6.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So made the following changes to your code.

In ElasticAdapter,

```
public Flux<Object> bulkIndex(JSONObject doc) {
    return bulkIndexDoc(doc)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic(), true)
            .doOnError(e -> System.out.print("Unable to index {}" + doc+ e));
}
```

Invoked subscribeOn(Scheduler, requestOnSeparateThread) on the Flux, Got to know about it from, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21507

In FluxClient,

```
Flux<String> responseFlux = client.get()
              .uri("/test3")
              .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                  httpHeaders.set("Accept", "text/event-stream");
              })
              .retrieve()
              .bodyToFlux(String.class);
responseFlux.delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Added "Accept" header as "text/event-stream" and delayed Flux elements.

With the above changes, was able to get the response in real time from the server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Are there any methods on the client/flux object which can be used to identify if the Flux is 'complete' ?

Comment: You may try adding a callback through the doOnComplete(Runnable runnable), may be something like, responseFlux.delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("UpStream has completed")).subscribe(System.out::println);